# Undertow properties default values

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

We're currently tuning our services that uses undertow but we can't find the default values of the following properties:

```
server.undertow.worker-threads
server.undertow.io-threads
```

We learned that undertow is using `org.xnio.Options` in setting-up the threads but can't find any default values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/Undertow.java

```
...
    ioThreads = Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 2);
    workerThreads = ioThreads * 8;
...
```

Comment: May I know how to override these properties? The undertow properties mentioned in the question is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Spring boot/Undertow, the properties to override are as follows :

**Example :**

```
server.undertow.threads.io=50
server.undertow.threads.worker=50
```